# Closure of multiplication of Cong. classes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, field-theory

In mod p, let k be the smallest positive integer such that [a]^k = [1].

Show that {[a],[a]²,.....,[a]^k} is closed under multiplication.

This is part of a larger problem overall and I have no idea how to show this. Any tips?

Comment: What is $[a]^i \cdot [a]^j$, i.e., the product of two random elements of your set?  Does it happen to be an element of your set?

Comment: As far as I know, it is [a]^(I+j). As for whether not it is a member of the set, I cannot see why it is. That is why I asked.

Comment: Is it a power of $[a]$?  Are all the powers of $[a]$ in your set?

Comment: I don't know. I see no reason that 1, 2, ... k would be a fully set of residues.

Comment: Why do you think $2$ is in the list $\{[a], [a]^2, \dots, [a]^k = 1\}$?  For instance, modulo 5, [4] produces the list $\{[4], [4]^2 = [1]\}$.

Comment: I don't understand the question. I thought 2 was in the list because I am just listing everything up to k.

Comment: The question means:  pick some $a$ and some prime $p$.  Find the least positive power of $[a]$ in the integers modulo $p$, $k$, satisfying $[a]^k \cong [1]$.  Show that the set of residue classes $\{[a], [a]^2, [a]^3, \dots ,[a]^{k-1}, [a]^k = 1\}$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why would I pick these things in a proof concerning any a, and any p? I have picked a few and verified that the theorem is true in those cases, but that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: At this point:  I can't guess what you've tried.  I can't guess what you've figured out from trying things.  I can't guess what you're stuck on.  None of those things appear in your problem description nor in these comments.  So, ..., what is the *actual* problem you're having?

Comment: The problem I'm having is showing that [a]^(i+j) is equal to one of the other classes in the set. I don't know of any information that could lead me to that conclusion.

Comment: Is $[a]^{i+j}$ a power of $[a]$?  Does the set contain all powers of $[a]$?

Comment: Yes, it is a power of [a]. If I knew that the set contained all powers of [a], I suppose I wouldn't be here :). I see no reason that 1, ..., k is a full set of residues.

Comment: Basically, I do know what closure means, and I know what my goal is, I am having trouble seeing a means to that end.

Comment: Nobody claims the set of powers of $[a]$ is a *full set of residues*.  The question only asks "if you multiply two of them together, do you get another one?"

Comment: Of course, but I thought that showing that would be an intermediate step; I understand what the question asks, I understand what closure means. I just don't see any reason to say that [a]^(I+j) is one of the extant members of the set.

Comment: What power of $[a]$ is **not** in the set?

Comment: [a]^(k+1), [a]^(k+2), ...

Comment: $[a]^{k+1} \cong [a][a]^{k} \cong [a] \cdot 1 \cong [a]$, and so on, cyclically repeating the list.

Comment: Oh, surely. I'm with you, I will see where that takes me. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.